# A property of linearly compact module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a noetherian local ring, $E$ the injective hull of $R/\mathfrak{m}$, $S=\operatorname{End}_R(E)$ and $M$ a linearly compact and discrete $R-$module. Show that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,E)$ is a linearly compact $S-$module.

This result may be founded in  *T. Onodera,  Linearly compact modules and  cogenerators (Theorem 6, Col. 2)* but I can't have it now.

Please help me some hint or refrence. Thank you.